# Image with encoded title not accessible by absolute path. PHP

Tags: php, image, character-encoding, urlencode, cyrillic

Faced a problem some images has such names in file system:
**%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-2.jpg**

Without encoding it's cyrillic letters `Без-имени-2.jpg`

So, methods `is_file` and `file_exists` return false with such absolute path(example):

```
$filename = '/home/dev/.../projects/.../httpdocs/upload/iblock/9c0/Без-имени-2.jpg';
```

I also tried to access the file by its encoded name, but to no avail
[Console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lBQ4.png)

Only re-uploading images helps, but there are a lot of them.

Comment: The file name is URL encoded isnt it? Could do `$filename = '/home/dev/.../projects/.../httpdocs/upload/iblock/9c0/' . urlencode('Без-имени-2.jpg');`

Comment: one way to work around it is not to use Без-имени-2 or %D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-2 but instead the hash of the file contents, you can store the actual name and other metadata about the file and its actual location in a database

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue with the encoding

try this

```
iconv('iso-8859-5', 'utf-8', $filename)
```

check this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

I hope it't helpful

Comment: Thanks, it might be usefull, but I've already spent 4 hours to reupload pics, cause client noticed bug)))
I'll try this if such problem happen again)